# How to reposition mac desktop in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, macos

Is there a function that allows you to manipulate the desktop like Dashboard->Manage Widgets?

The desktop appears to reposition itself and slide up. What I want to do is not just slide the desktop when my toolbar is temporarily active but have the entire desktop resize. I assume if you can grab a handle to manipulate the desktop like Dashboard, additional similar operations should be possible.

Desktop windows continue to redraw and operate normally so this is not a screen cap that is just repositioned.

Is Dashboard executing a desktop animation function? or executing a complex set of functions to emulate this effect? or private API? Anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is emulation. It's probably a window at a very high window level that grabs a screen cap of your desktop to use as its background then animates the rest.

In any case, there's no Cocoa function to let you do this with your own UI.

Comment: That's like the trick used before to simulate transparent or semi-transparent backgrounds but we know modern OSes no long require that for compositing. My guess is there must be a function to access the core OGL plane to move the desktop. I'm not hinting-- this just what I think based on how it draws the windows effects and animations

Comment: Would love to know the function/library if it exists. :-)

Comment: This is easy to test: start playing a movie in QuickTime Player. Open Dashboard and click the Manage Widgets button. The movie keeps playing!